# Bedeutungswörterbuch versus «normales» Wörterbuch

Tags: meaning

Ich will ein paar gebrauchte Bücher von Amazon kaufen, und ein Buch, das ich besonders kaufen will, ist ein echtes Deutsches Wörterbuch. Das Problem, dem ich jetzt begegne ist: ich habe ein Bedeutungswörterbuch and ein «normales» Wörterbuch gefunden, aber ich weiß, nicht was der Unterschied dazwischen ist. Im Internet finde ich nichts Hilfreiches, das mir hilft, diese Wörter/Bücher zu unterscheiden. Sind sie dasselbe? Gibt's sogar einen Unterschied dazwischen?

[Wörterbuch Deutsch Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3411046635)

[Bedeutungswörterbuch Deutsch Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3411209119)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich habe mit meiner Lehrerin gesprochen (die hat die beiden Bücher), und wir haben die verglichen.

- Das  Wörterbuch "Der Kleine Duden", das «normale», schien mehr um die Verwendung zu gehen (Es hatte Beispiele, Rechtschreibung usw), aber es hatte keine Definitionen.
- Das Bedeutungswörterbuch hatte Definitionen, Beispiele, Bilder usw. (Es war, was ich ein «normales» Wörterbuch nennen würde).

Answer (score 2):

**Bedeutungswörterbuch**

Hier steht in der Regel die genaue Bedeutungsbeschreibung eines Stichworts.

Mehrere Unterbedeutungen eines Wortes, mitunter werden situations- bzw. kontextabhängige Zusatzinformationen angegeben.

Ist die Benutzung eines Wortes nur in Bezug auf bestimmte Lebewesen oder Objekte möglich, sowie Sach- und Zusatzinformationen, die über die reine Bedeutungserklärung hinausgehen werden erwähnt, um sie praziser oder besser verständlich zu machen.

Im Gegensatz zu den Erklärungen in Enzyklopädien, die den Benutzern Informationen zu Dingen, historischen Begebenheiten, Personen etc. (also: Sachinformationen) bieten, findet man in einem Wörterbucheintrag üblicherweise Informationen zur Sprache und ihren Bedeutungen.

Die Erklärungen zu bestimmten Nebenbedeutungen, die sich nur aus konkreten Kontexten ergeben bzw. auf Wendungen, Redensarten oder Sprichwörter zutreffen, werden hinter dem entsprechenden Wort oder der Redewendung angegeben.

Comment: Und was ist jetzt mit dem "normalen" Wörterbuch??